# ‎If $\|f_{n}-f\|_{u}<\epsilon$‎, ‎then $\vert f(x) \vert<\epsilon$ if $x\notin \operatorname{supp}(f_{n})$? Why?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

‎My question is of the proof of this theorem: ‎If $X$ is an LCH (locally compact Hausdorff) space‎, ‎$C_{0}(X)=\overline{C_{c}(X)}$ in the uniform metric in ‎following.‎

‎Proof‎: ‎Let $\{f_{n}\}\subseteq C_c(X)$ such that $f_{n}\longrightarrow f\in C(X)$ uniformly‎, ‎then for each $\epsilon>0$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\|f_{n}-f\|_{u}<\epsilon$‎. ‎Then $\vert f(x) \vert<\epsilon$ if $x\notin \operatorname{supp}(f_{n})$. Why?‎

Comment: Dose $\|f_{n}-f\|_{‎u}‎‎=‎‎sup‎\vert ‎f‎_{‎n‎}‎(x)-f(x)‎‎ ‎\vert‎‎‎‎$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\|f_n-f\|_u < \epsilon$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$. Also, if $x \notin \operatorname{supp} f_n$, then $f_n(x) = 0$. I assume you can finish the argument.